# Executable Jar with extern properties

Tags: java, properties

I made a java program with a properties file named config.properties.
It works perfectly on Eclipse.

I'm trying to create an executable jar for this programe.
Using the classic method (right click on project, export, executable jar file...) i get a working jar but when i try to edit my config.properties file the changes are not taken in account for the following execution of my jar.

How can I get, on the one hand an executable jar and on the other hand a config.properties file (outside of my Jar) that can be edited by the users to change the parameters of my Jar code ?

Currently my property file is stocked in /src and declared like this :

**public static ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("config");**

When I need to use one of the properties of this file in my java code I use :

**bundle.getString("Car.Color");**

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You wanna edit the properties inside the jar? Cant you use a external file

Comment: In fact, I want my propertie file to be external so that when a user can change the parameters easily whenever he wants.

Comment: Better way is to use the File system, and save it with the .properties extension, then use Properties p = new// ; p.load(new File("C:/dir/f.properties");

Answer (score 0):

Edit your classpath to include a directory within which your properties file is located. For example:

```
java -classpath C:\java\MyClasses com.myapp.RunIt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't really understand what that means.

Could you please give me an example of where I have to add this line? It's my first programming attempt in java.